# I need AutoCompleteTextView in editable format on clicking image icon

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, onclicklistener, autocompletetextview

Here I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` and an image view it;s an arrow that is placed just right side of this `AutoCompleteTextView`. When I click on that image icon I need this `AutoCompleteTextView` to be in editable form means the same effect when we touch directly in this `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
 <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:id="@+id/auto"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:hint="Select Location"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="dropclick"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: is this what you are looking for? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android:dropDownAnchor

Comment: You want an `AutoCompleteTextView` with a spinner?? because if yes then I've all the code written as I've implemented it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Quessema Aroua is good but here's what you can do without a library.
Implement this code in XML.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:hint="@string/source"
            android:id="@+id/actv5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/actv4"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:dropDownHeight="155dp"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/imv2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/actv5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/actv5"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/actv5"
            />
```

You can choose whatever layout you need but mine is `ConstraintLayout`.
And this in YourActivity.java

```
    locnames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Loc_names);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                    locnames);

            autoText1 =(AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv4);
            autoText1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            autoText1.setThreshold(1);
            autoText1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //autoText1.showDropDown();
                    hideKeyBoard(view);
                    //String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    selected = position;
                }
            });
            /*autoText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View arg0) {

                    autoText1.showDropDown(); }
            });*/

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imv1);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View arg0) {

                    autoText1.showDropDown(); }
            });
```

Also You should set-up a String of locnames as in mine in Strings.XML like this:

```
 <string-array name="Loc_names">

        <item>India</item>
        <item>America</item>
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>Russia</item>
        <item>Australia</item>
        <item>China</item>
 </string-array>
```

The Message part in code of YourActivity.java here shows the same pop-up/spinner by clicking anywhere on the `AutoCompleteTextView` which removes the need of using an `ImageView` (arrow) but you want an `ImageView` that's why I've made this code a message/comment.

```
/*autoText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final View arg0) {

                        autoText1.showDropDown(); }
                });*/
```

As I've directly copied this from my project, you should replace all ids/names according to you.
**Some images for reference**

1. This is normal `AutoCompleteTextView`.

[image]

2. This is `AutoCompleteTextView` with a `Spinner`.

[image]

3. This is AutoCompleteTextView with some text entered and text
   filtered in the spinner.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use [EditSpinner](https://github.com/xyxyLiu/Edit-Spinner) auto complete spinner lib.

Add it to gradle :

```
compile 'com.reginald:editspinner:1.0.0'
```

add the view to your xml file :

```
 <com.reginald.editspinner.EditSpinner
     android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:dropDownDrawable="@mipmap/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"
     app:dropDownDrawableSpacing="35dp" />
```

prepare your adapter :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, itemList);
```

set adapter to your `EditSpinner` :

```
autoCompleteOperationDetail.setAdapter(operationDetailArrayAdapter);
```